# Dynamic Languages on / off the Java JVM

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, groovy, clojure

I'm interested in learning a dynamic language after at least 10 years on the Java platform.  There are two choices that I was considering.  One, learning one such as Clojure / Groovy that ride on top of the Java JVM.  Secondly, a language off the JVM, which would include Ruby / Rails or Erlang.

Having knowing alot about the Java side, I'd like to choose a JVM based solution, but considering an off the JVM solution.

My question is:

- ***What advantages / disadvantages would I get by choosing a language off of the Java JVM?***

One of my biggest pain points is deployment memory footprint.  I'd like to have a solution that allows low memory consumption, because most cloud / ISP providers require high dollar for anything greater the 512 MB / server.  I've been so used to using High Memory JVM's which just don't work well with my costs.  Maybe this isn't a concern for using clojure or groovy, but I'd expect a high memory footprint since it's running on the JVM.

I've already started using Ruby / Rails lately and I've been impressed with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go off the JVM then you have a good tool you can use in the cases where the JVM is poorly suited, like command line utilities where JVM startup time is really annoying.

If you go with **Clojure you get both**, with the clojure compiler you can produce classes for the JVM and with the **ClojureScript** compiler you can produce javascript that will run on very nearly anything.

My personal and therefore unverifiable advice is to go with the option that will expand your programming mind *cough clojure* but I am personally rather biased.

Comment: I agree that if you want the most control over memory use and startup time, then none of the languages are a good choice.  Time to switch you using C. ;)

Comment: I agree, +1 for "expanding programming mind cough clojure" ;-) My personal path of exploring new languages in the past few years has been java -> groovy -> (j)ruby -> emacs lisp -> clojure. Looking back, I wish I would have learned a lisp (clojure!) earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You could try JRuby to support ruby on and off a JVM.

I wouldn't assume that using JVM means using lots of memory.  This depends on how you use the JVM.  Using a profiler and more  compact data structures can minimise memory usage.  You can look at using C++, but if you are not careful C++ can use more memory. (But not if you know what you are doing)

How much memory you use is more about how you develop your program than which language you use.

Answer (score 0):

For a low footprint solution, you may wish to consider JavaScript coupled with the V8 JS engine and [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) technology